# I keep getting a blank admin page?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site and now for some reason it no longer allows me to make changes via the admin backend. I just have this blank GUI, none of which make any change if you click on them

I just added a plugin called Monster insights to align the site with google analytics and since then I get this result. I have tried to rename the plugins folder to manually remove them out of the equation and still no luck. I have reviewed the Log file with little luck as well.

[04-Jun-2019 08:57:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_is_recovery_mode() in /home/erwinb411/public_html/wp-admin/includes/update.php on line 840

[04-Jun-2019 08:18:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/home/erwinb411/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme52521/includes/register-plugins.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in

Answer (score 1):

i think is a problem of plugin's compatibility in your site.

Have you try to update wordpress core, plugin and theme?

if after update all you have the same problem is an compatibility issue.

Let me know.

Comment: "I have tried to rename the plugins folder to manually remove them out of the equation and still no luck."

Comment: In any case, I recommend updating theme and wordpress core, not only plugin. Try to do that, and see the result.